# Can't run pyspark DataFrame function take() in Zepplin

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am very new to Zepplin and have been trying to move my code from jupyter notebooks. One this I noticed is while `df.show(n)` works really well, but `df.take(n)` is not working. There is no error, it just does not show the output. Even `df.count()` is not showing any either.

I also tested the class of the df is really dataframe or not. `print(type(df))` is showing it as `<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>`.

Just wanted to know, is there some limitations of Zepplin with respect `pyspark` ?

As I have to use Zepplin going forward so it will be useful for me if someone shed some light.

Comment: did you try to assign it to some variable? e.g. v = df.take(n) and then do some printing of v?

Comment: thanks assigning variables worked.. would like to know what is the problem, so that,going forward, I can predict such behavior of Zeppelin

Comment: Even I am facing problem in defining a function it is showing invalid syntax for def f(arg):

Comment: I am not a zeppelin expert but I would guess that for some reason (in configuration or something else) when you run a cell it doesn't print the last value (which is the way jupyter works). So if you do something that simply returns a value it does not get printed. When you print then the printed values appear. I do not think this is a spark issue.

Comment: Please share your log in the `logs/` when you execute `df.take(n)` or `df.count()`?

Comment: I am unable to find logs.. there is no traceback

Comment: The log files should be in the `[YOUR ZEPPELINHOME]/logs/`.